# cakephp form action gets folder name

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have set controller: books, action: index to my default page mydomain.com/myfolder/

I have a form on the index page but the action of the form gets the my folder added to it.

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
'url' => 'array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'add')'
    ));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

The output

```
<form action="/myfolder/books/add" id="BookIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>
    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="BookTitle">Title</label>
        <input name="data[Book][title]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="BookTitle" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
 echo $this->Form->create("Book", array("action"=>"add"));
```